# Using string[range]=new_val while respecting UTF8 in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, ruby-1.8

I have code like

```
text[from..to] = text_insertion
```

The problem is that `from` and `to` are given counting UTF8 encoded characters as one char while the code above counts byte-wise in Ruby 1.8.7

I have to use Ruby 1.8.7

Which gem could I use to make my code work? I also can rewrite it to use `String#substr` or something similar, but I haven't found any lib that gives me methods that respect UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ActiveSupport's `String#mb_chars` method. It let's you write something like this:

```
text.mb_chars[from..to] = text_insertion
```

It is available in all versions of ActiveSupport since 2.2.